# What type of solver does Mathematica use in LinearSolve

Tags: linear-algebra, implementation-details

I have a question regarding linear equation solvers. For a specific 9-diagonal matrix, every method I tried in C++ (Gaus, GCC, BICGTAB) didn't work (even though they worked for other matrices). But in *Mathematica*, `LinearSolve` gave a solution for this matrix.

What type of solver does *Mathematica* use in `LinearSolve`?

Comment: It is not diagonal matrix how edit gpap but 9-diagonal matrix from FEM discretization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Documentation on Numerical Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#5783):

- Machine-precision matrices are typically converted to a special internal representation for processing.
- `SparseArray` with rules involving patterns uses cylindrical algebraic decomposition to find connected array components. Sparse arrays are stored internally using compressed sparse row formats, generalized for tensors of arbitrary rank.
- For dense arrays, LAPACK algorithms extended for arbitrary precision are used when appropriate.
- BLAS technology is used to optimize for particular machine architectures. 
  `LUDecomposition`, `Inverse`, `RowReduce`, and `Det` use Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting. `LinearSolve` uses the same methods, together with adaptive iterative improvement for high-precision numbers.
- For sparse arrays, `LinearSolve` uses UMFPACK multifrontal direct solver methods and with `Method->"Krylov"` uses Krylov iterative methods preconditioned by an incomplete LU factorization. For high-precision numbers, it uses adaptive iterative improvement methods. `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors` use ARPACK Arnoldi methods.